# grgit NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, grgit

Gradle throws a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to execute a grgit task.

Start of `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//
//

import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

task clone << {
    File dir = new File('contrib/otherstuff')
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: dir, uri: 'https://github.com/someguy/otherstuff.git')
    }
    // TODO else (pull)
}


project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn clone
}

// rest omitted
```

Output:

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:src:myproject:clone FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/me/src/myproject/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':src:myproject:clone'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.937 secs
```

Line 20 is the call to `Grgit.clone()`.

Do I need to add groovy as a build dependency (which the error message seems to indicate)? How and where would I add it?

EDIT: gradle version is 1.10, if it matters.

Comment: Have you missed `apply plugin: 'groovy'`?

Comment: Adding `apply plugin: 'groovy'` gives me `Could not find property 'plugin' on project ':src:myproject'` for that line. NB: the omitted parts of `build.gradle` contain no reference to anything related to grgit, so if a required line is not in the snippet, it’s safe to assume it’s nowhere in the file.

Comment: @user149408, why does your error is for task `':src:myproject:clone'`, I mean two levels of error, can you also run `./gradlew tasks --all` for me?

Comment: @chenrui Output is here: https://pastebin.com/TUX52Vzb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve managed to solve it.

grgit-1.2.0 appears to depend on groovy. Adding a `classpath` entry for groovy in the `buildscript`/`dependencies` block resulted in a different error:

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:src:myproject:clone FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/me/src/myproject/build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':src:myproject:clone'.
> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.AuthConfig$Option do not match. Expected -1 but got 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.295 secs
```

Further research revealed that this might stem from a version incompatibility (as I’m stuck with Gradle 1.10 for other reasons).

Eventually I solved it by going back to grgit-0.7.0. Now my git task works and the repo gets cloned.

Comment: You should try and raise the priority of any "upgrading gradle" cards you have in the backlog ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As @user149408 pointed out the Gradle version (v1.10 vs v2.10) mismatch, I dug a little bit further:

[gradle-git-plugin commit for v0.7.0](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git/commit/30d49790e3de94a07c1e2cf13489b2161ad97cce) specifies the Gradle version used (v1.11), so the build with v1.10 works fine.

Because the Gradle plugin always built with `compile localGroovy()` and `compile gradleApi()` which comes from Gradle, then if it builds with Gradle 2.x, it would incur the Groovy mismatch error.

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':src:myproject:clone'.
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling

In fact, the combo of Gradle v2.10 and gradle-git v1.2.0 just works fine.

Some sample `build.gradle` similar structure as in the question.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.2.0'
    }
}

import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

task clone << {
    File dir = new File('contrib/gs-spring-boot')
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: dir, uri: 'https://github.com/chenrui333/gs-spring-boot.git')
    }
    // TODO else (pull)
}
```

`./gradlew clone` would give you:

```
$ ls contrib/gs-spring-boot/
CONTRIBUTING.adoc   LICENSE.code.txt    LICENSE.writing.txt README.adoc         complete            initial             test
```

Hope it helps!